# Which maven2 archetype to use for a Swing desktop application?

Tags: swing, maven-2, desktop-application

I want to build a small Swing application today and use *maven2* for the build/test lifecycle.

But I don't know which archetype I should choose to create the project. Is there something available for a desktop application? Or do I start with the **simple** archetype (no #3 in the interactive setup)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would choose the simple or no archetype at all. Perhaps the [*Maven Quickstart Archetype*](http://maven.apache.org/archetypes/maven-archetype-quickstart/).

Swing is part of Java (at least in more recent versions). I am not aware of any archetype that is targeted at Swing desktop applications.

Some previous posts:

[Maven2 & Swing projects: Build & run swing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681235/maven2-swing-projects-build-run-swing-application)

[How to create a swing application using maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2191656/create-swing-application-using-maven-2)

Comment: Do you have any information about creating a JNLP webstart file with maven?

Comment: Ah, the 1st linked answer already had a pointer to the maven webstart plugin. I guess I can award you the bounty right away. %-)

Answer (score 0):

The Quickstart Maven archetype works well.  It produces a minimal structure useful for Swing and command line applications.

Answer (score 0):

I was creating the same boilerplate on every little swing project I was creating, so they could have the same look and feel, so I created one that suffices my needs... As some assets are destined specifically to me, you would probably have to change them, but I find that a good starting point:

[It is hosted on github](https://github.com/lgdamy/swing-archetype)